# Calling method isn't returning string

Tags: ruby

I created a method to count a substring `'e'` in a string passed as an argument. If there isn't a substring `'e'` in the string, it should return `"There is no \"e\"."` I am trying to achieve this:

- How many times `'e'` is in a string.
- If given string doesn't contain any `"e"`, return `"There is no "e"."`
- if given string is empty, return empty string.
- if given string is `nil`, return `nil`.

This is my code:

```
def find_e(s)
  if !s.include?("e")
    "There is no \"e\"."
  elsif s.empty?
     ""
  else s.nil?
     nil
  end
  s.count("e").to_s
end

find_e("Bnjamin")
```

It skips the `if` statement and it still uses the method `count`. Why is this?

Comment: You've flipped else and elsif.

Comment: Sorry wrong code, I have changed.

Comment: It's still wrong.

Comment: There is no `return` statement to force the function returns before reaching the  `s.count("e").to_s` statement. It always executes and, because it is the last value computed by the function, it is also the value returned by the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you could move your `string.count` to the `else` statement in your `if`, because actually you're making your method return the quantity of `e` passed in the `count` method over your string, but what happens inside the `if` isn't being used:

```
def find_e(s)
  if s.nil?
    nil
  elsif s.empty?
    ''
  elsif !s.include?("e")
    "There is no \"e\"."
  else
    s.count("e").to_s
  end
end

p find_e("Bnjamin") # => "There is no \"e\"."
p find_e("Benjamin") # => "1"
p find_e(nil) # => nil
p find_e('') # => ""
```

And also your validations must be in order, first check `nil` values, then empty values, and then the rest, if you don't then you'll get some `undefined method ___ for nil:NilClass` errors.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a hard time using the method you wrote. In the next method, you'll need a new `case` statement to test if `find_e` returned `nil`, an empty string, a string with a number or `"no e"`.

This method would be a bit more consistent:

```
def count_e(string_or_nil)
  count = string_or_nil.to_s.count("e")
  if count == 0
    "There is no \"e\"."
  else
    count
  end
end

puts count_e("Covfefe")
# 2
puts count_e("Bnjamin")
# There is no "e".
puts count_e("")
# There is no "e".
puts count_e(nil)
# There is no "e".
```

But really, if there's no `e` in the input, just returning `0` would be the most logical behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your count method in a branch of the `if/else` statement, or else it will be evaluated last every time. Without an explicit return statement Ruby will return the last statement, so putting the method outside the `if/else` branch on the last line guarantees it will always be hit. Also, `nil` can be converted to an empty string by calling `#to_s`, so you can remove one of your branches by converting `s.to_s`, calling `empty?` and returning `s`

```
def find_e(s)
  if s.to_s.empty?
    s
  elsif !s.include?("e")
    "There is no \"e\"."
  else
    s.count("e").to_s
  end
end
```

If you just return `0` whether you get `nil`, an empty string, or a string without `e`, you can make it one line

```
def find_e(s)
  s.to_s.count("e").to_s
end
```

If it were me I'd probably return an Integer, which can always be converted to a String later. `puts` and `"#{}"` will implicitly call `to_s` for you anway. Then you can use that integer return in your presentation logic.

```
def count_e(input)
  input.to_s.count("e")
end

def check_for_e(input)
  count = count_e(input)
  count > 0 ? count.to_s : "There's no \"e\"."
end

check_for_e("Covfefe") # => "2"
check_for_e("Bnjamin") # => "There's no \"e\"."
check_for_e(nil) # => "There's no \"e\"."
check_for_e("") # => "There's no \"e\"."
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, methods return the last statement in their body. Your method's last statement is always `s.count("e").to_s`, since that lies outside of the `if` statements.

Comment: If I want the count method to be included I have to use it in my 'if' statement?

Comment: More accurate will be: *"Ruby returns the last evaluated expression when no explicit return is provided"*.